# Write anonymous expression as lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, console-application, anonymous-methods

How to write the same 'Anonymous Expression' in 'Lambda Expression.'

```
namespace AnonymouseAndLambdaExpression
{
    // Delegate
    public delegate bool NumberHandler(int number);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //..
            NumberHandler _NumberHandler = delegate (int Number) { return Number == 100; };

            bool result = _NumberHandler(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}" , result);
        }
    }
}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: @SLaks Yes i did...i read alot about Lambda Expression when working with Lists etc...but this one is new for me...

Comment: ReSharper to the rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `NumberHandler` takes **one** parameter of type `int` and returns a `bool` it would just be:

```
NumberHandler _numberHandler = (int number) => number == 100;
```

or:

```
NumberHandler _numberHandler = number => number == 100;
```

Further, I'd avoid reinventing the wheel and instead use `Predicate<int>` i.e.

```
Predicate<int> _numberHandler = number => number == 100;
```

I'd also highly suggest you take a read on [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: Thanks you so much @Aomine.